# scp files from yesterday

Tags: linux, unix, scp

I want to copy files from a remote Server to a local server. The problem is: I only want to copy the files from yesterday.
The remote server is writing logfiles and at 23:59 the logrotation is compressing it to a file [name]_[date].log.gz. At 6:00 in the morning a cronjob on the local server needs to copy the file previously created from the remote server. Does anyone know how to do this?

Regards,
Alex

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use a script like this

```
for i in `find /interface/outbound/Web -type f -ctime -1`
do
scp $i user@$destination_server:/destination_directory/
done
```

in particular the command find as the following features for example:

```
find . -ctime -1 # which are created less than 1 day ago from currrent folder.
find . -ctime +2 # finds files which are created older than 2 days from currrent folder.
```

where `ctime` is the creation time. It's also possible to use the modification time `mtime` in this way:

```
find . -mtime 0   # find files modified between now and 1 day ago
find . -mtime -1  # find files modified less than 1 day ago
find . -mtime 1   # find files modified between 24 and 48 hours ago
find . -mtime +1  # find files modified more than 48 hours ago
```

More information in [**man find**](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=find&sektion=1)

**Edit:**

To have the same behaviour from remote to local you can use something like:

```
latest_file=`ssh user@destination_server find /pathtoDir -type f -ctime -1`
/usr/bin/scp user@destination_server:$latest_file /local_dir 
echo SCP Completed.
```

At this moment I haven't a Unix environment to make some tests.

Comment: Hi and thanks for you answer. You are testing the files on the local server. I need to find the file from yesterday on the remote server.
localServer (where the script is run) should get the file from yesterday from the remoteServer.

Comment: Don't forget to vote for the correct answer if this solution works for you

Comment: Since 2013 (the time of this answer), websites such as [BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ) and https://shellcheck.net have popped up which assist in analysing potential problems. So a small update to this answer might come in handy. Here I would like to point out [Looping over list of files](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)